# Having multiple StreamSockets open at the same time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I've been attempting to use the new PeerFinder in Windows Phone 8 to discover instances of my application near me. The problem is that I need to communicate with all of them and, more importantly, listen to incoming messages from all of them, so I've decided opening multiple StreamSockets and listening to them that way.

I've only got two development devices, but as soon as I connect device1 to device2, PeerFinder stops listing device2 in the available peers list. Now, my dilemma is the following:

- Does PeerFinder detect that a socket is open with that device and automatically omits it from the available peers list? or
- PeerFinder only supports one connection at a time (frowny face) and I have to use something else to build my app? If so, what? :D

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about this, but is it possible that the max connections of Windows-Phone is reached?
Did you try to increase the max Connections? [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: ServicePointManager doesn't seem to have been implemented in Windows Phone :( I tried including System.Net but it won't find it